# First steps after activating ECB first time

Tags: emacs, emacs-ecb

I have ECB installed and autostarted in emacs:

```lisp
(require 'semantic/analyze)
(provide 'semantic-analyze)
(provide 'semantic-ctxt)
(provide 'semanticdb)
(provide 'semanticdb-find)
(provide 'semanticdb-mode)
(provide 'semantic-load)
(semantic-mode 1)

(setq stack-trace-on-error t)
(require 'ecb)
(require 'ecb-autoloads)
(setq ecb-auto-activate 1) 
(ecb-winman-winring-enable-support)
```

ECB shows its "First steps after activating ECB first time" info node each time. How do I stop it doing that?

**Edit**:

Of course brute force solves it:

```lisp
(run-with-idle-timer 0.05 nil '(lambda () (kill-buffer "*info*")))
```

but I thought - may be there is a ECB variable that knows wither it activation of the ECB is for the first time or not.

**Edit**:

So one has to put for example:

```
 (setq ecb-source-path (quote (("/home/boris/its/plts" "plts"))))
```

This tell ECB that the project is at `/home/boris/its/plts`, and should be reffered to as `plts`.

Comment: works also by putting in custom.el: `'(ecb-source-path (quote (("/home/boris/its/plts" "plts"))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the source code, it seems that customising the variable `ecb-source-path` should prevent the info buffer being displayed. The relevant code is in the `ecb-activate--impl` function:

```
;; if we activate ECB first time then we display the node "First steps" of
;; the online-manual
(ignore-errors
    (when (null ecb-source-path)
        (let ((ecb-show-help-format 'info))
            (ecb-show-help)
            (Info-goto-node "First steps"))))
```

As you can see, the info buffer is displayed if `ecb-source-path` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Edit ecb.el and comment the next 4 lines (around line 1590 in ecb-2.40):

```
    (ignore-errors
      (when (null ecb-source-path)
        (let ((ecb-show-help-format 'info))
          (ecb-show-help)
          (Info-goto-node "First steps"))))
```